# Errors with NVIDIA drivers --"cannot determine support level" and "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, gpu

I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it and would like to run my code on the GPU and not on the CPU. Unfortunately I have problems with it. I tried to install the driver (nvidia-driver-470 and also nvidia-driver-510) but they are apparently not detected.

When I type the command `nvidia-smi` i get:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

With the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` I get:

```
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510-server: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002520sv00001462sd000012F2bc03sc00i00
vendor : NVIDIA Corporation

driver : nvidia-driver-510 - third-party non-free

driver : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free

driver : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended

driver : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free

driver : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

With the command `sudo lspci` I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #2
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2520 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

With `dkms status` i get:

```
nvidia, 470.103.01, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I have very little experience with Ubuntu and for the first time would like to use the GPU.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lspci`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just added "sudo lspci" in the question above. After that I tried your suggestion "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall". I still have the same problem. regarding to your second question, I just tried all the time to install different drivers. One more thing what i always have to do in terminal it to give the following command "sudo systemctl stop systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket" Because otherwise my laptop becomes very loud and loads the cpu, i don't know if this has to do with it.

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Comment: with "dkms status" i get: nvidia, 470.103.01, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed    @Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? how can i check this?

Comment: *how can i check this?* You open the UEFI ("BIOS") settings and check. IF enabled then disabled it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto @ 
heynnema, yes it was enabled and now i changed it to disabled. But the problem is still there.

Comment: a Google search of "NVIDIA Corporation Device 2520" shows that pci=realloc as a kernel boot param may help (edit it into the /etc/default/grub file at the "quiet splash" words).  Also, trying the 22.04 beta release may also help with a more current kernel.

Comment: @ubfan1, I have changed it (instead:    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"    to     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=realloc") as you said, do you have idea what I should do further.

Comment: Now sudo update-grub, reboot, and see what happens. If no help, try the 22.04 daily download from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/.  rtx 3060 on ubuntu may be another google search that may have some suggestions for your new hardware. I've been using the 510 driver without problems, so your new hardware probably should be using that  also.

Comment: @ubfan1, thank you very much! i did this sudo update-grub, reboot and now the GPU is successfully detected.

Comment: You may write up your own answer, to help others and gain some reputation points.  After a few days, if it gets upvoted, you may accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for me was in /etc/default/grub. I needed to change there this code line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=realloc"`. After that I executed the `sudo update-grub` command then `reboot` command from the terminal.